# Magento 2 split order total not calculate properly

Tags: magento2, order-splitting, order-totals

I am working on Magento Ver. 2.2 I have split order using following code. It split the order but order total is not calculate properly for each order. In short each order display complete/original order total.

```
public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null) {
        $quote  = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $paymentMethodString = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();

        $billingAddress  = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        unset($billingAddress['id']);
        unset($billingAddress['quote_id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['quote_id']);

        $itemsPerVendor = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $itemsPerVendor[$item->getItemId()][] = $item;
        }

        foreach ($itemsPerVendor as $vendor => $items) {
            $quoteSplit = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $quoteSplit->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomer($quote->getCustomer());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomerIsGuest($quote->getCustomerIsGuest());
            if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() === self::METHOD_GUEST) {
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
            }

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $item->setId(null);
                $quoteSplit->addItem($item);
            }

            $quoteSplit->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
            $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);


            $quoteSplit->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

            $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setMethod($paymentMethodString);
            if ($paymentMethod) {
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setQuote($quoteSplit);
                $data = $paymentMethod->getData();
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }

            $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_before', ['quote' => $quoteSplit]);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);
            $order    = $this->submit($quoteSplit);
            $orders[] = $order;

            if (null == $order) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.')
                );
            }

        }
        $quote->setIsActive(false);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

        $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_all_after', ['orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $quote]);

        return $order->getId();
    }
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar difficult recently and the solution I created was set the values manually, *below your items foreach* just like:

```
    // Retrieve values.
    $tax        = $item->getData('tax_amount');
    $discount   = $item->getData('discount_amount');
    $itemPrice  = $item->getPrice();
    $itemQty    = $item->getQty();
    $finalPrice = ($itemPrice * $itemQty);

    // Set addresses.
    $quoteSplit->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
    $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);

    // Add shipping amount if product is not virual.
    if ($quoteSplit->hasVirtualItems() === false) {
        $shippingAmount = $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
    }

    // Recollect totals into the quote.
    foreach ($quoteSplit->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
        // Build grand total.
        $grandTotal = (($finalPrice + $shippingAmount + $tax) - $discount);
        $address->setBaseSubtotal($finalPrice);
        $address->setSubtotal($finalPrice);
        $address->setDiscountAmount($discount);
        $address->setTaxAmount($tax);
        $address->setBaseTaxAmount($tax);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal);
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
    }
...
```

Please take a look at this https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order/blob/v1.0.1/Plugin/QuoteManagement.php file for more reference.